# CSS: Dock element to bottom of page and its top to bottom of upper element?

Tags: css, layout, position

I need to glue an element to the bottom and to the top, but I want to keep a dynamic space from the top that another element goes in, I want the `top` to be that element size + some space.

How is this possible (Pure CSS preferred)?

**[Here](http://goo.gl/1WdyI)** is an example:

HTML:

```
<header id="header" class="center">
Hello and welcome to my demo!
</header>

<header id="slider" class="center">
    <img src="http://goo.gl/o6tho"/>
</header>

<div id="content" class="center">
    I want this area to be glued to the footer + 10px space
    And additionally, glued to the element on top of itself + 10px
    The slider can disappear, which should result in the content
    to grow and reach the heaader.
</div>

<footer class="center">
    All rights reserved.
</footer>
​
```

CSS:

```
.center
{
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;  
    right: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}

#header
{
    background: green;
    color: white;  
    height: 50px;
    position: fixed;    
    top: 0px;    
}

#slider
{
    height: 60px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 60px;
}
#slider img
{
    max-width: 100%;
}

#content
{
    background: beige;    
    height: 50px;
    bottom: 10px;
}

footer
{      
    background: blue;
    color: white;  
    height: 50px;
    position: fixed;    
    bottom:0px;
}
```

Comment: That is a confusing sentence

Comment: Can you post a screenshot/ascii art of desired result?

Comment: Question update, will expand more if necessary.

Comment: screenshot will be brilliant. you want it to "stick to the previous element and the bottom"??? or "stick to bottom if element is smaller than a page OR stick to element if bigger?

Comment: @CarlSaldanha Hey you got your [screenshot](http://jsfiddle.net/shimmy/PdMMu/5/) now.

Comment: @Jeff the link is right there, I'll make it bold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not sure with css but js you can try something like this:

```
document.getElementById('header').style.top = document.getElementById('newelement').style.height;
```

Right with the new element insert.

Comment: And I thought CSS3 has it all :'(

Comment: Sucky solution. I'm a former Silverlight dev. HTML+CSS3 is cool but XAML is zillion times cooler and more efficient. I wish they would make a pure HTML+CSS3+JS client-side code-generator instead of the Silverlight plugin, so we can continue to write SL. Life sucks and SL is dead...

Comment: I was also wondering if there is a way to have the page scrollbar control that 'content' area only, something like we see in [this](http://www.artofadambetts.com) page. Also, according to my CSS, is there a way to avoid setting the class `center` on all the elements?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do a CSS-only solution today would be to give `%` heights on all the elements.

At some point in the future, hopefully, we will all be able to use the new CSS for [grid layouts](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-grid-layout/) to accomplish exactly what you need.

Comment: That's impossible. I need the page to be compatible on any screen-size while retaining the header & footer at a fixed size.

Comment: I figured that might be the case. Looks like you can't do a CSS-only solution then. I would try a JavaScript solution next if I were you.

Answer (score -1):

This might be useful for you:

Create a `<div>` outside main-content div and give it a `position:relative`.

Comment: And how is this going to affect the current div that I want its top to be dependent?